# How to create a specific math-alphabetic letter?

Tags: symbols, mtpro, mathcal

I'm preparing an essay which should contain the following letter:

[image]

I'm a newbie in the world of TEX, and I don't know how to get it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried `\mathcal{Q}` (in math mode)?

Answer (score 5):

The glyph shown in your screenshot is a so-called "calligraphic" uppercase letter Q. Write `\mathcal{Q}` to typeset it, in math mode, in a LaTeX document.

Various math font packages provide a rather broad range of forms of (math-) calligraphic letters; see pp. 6 to 8 of the user guide of the `mathalfa` package for several dozen variants of calligraphic-Q;  type `texdoc mathalfa` at a command prompt to load the user guide in a pdf viewer. The package's user guide distinguishes among four [4!] main subtypes of calligraphic letters: "Upright", "Restrained", "Embellished", and "Heavily Sloped". In case you're curious: If no font packages are loaded, i.e., if just the basic Computer Modern fonts are loaded, `mathalfa` classifies the style of the glyph that's produced by `\mathcal{Q}` as "Restrained". In contrast, `mathalfa` classifies the style of the letter shown in your screenshot as "Embellished".

In order to generate the *specific glyph* shown in the screenshot you posted, you will need to load the `mtpro2` font package with the option `mtpcal`, i.e., run `\usepackage[mtpcal]{mtpro2}` in the preamble. Alternatively, you could run `\usepackage[cal=mt]{mathalfa}`, still in the preamble. With either setup, type `\mathcal{Q}` in the body of the document to generate the desired glyph.

Do be aware, though, that the `mtpro2` (short for "MathTime Professional II") font package is *not free of charge* and is thus not likely to be installed as part of your TeX distribution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
%%\usepackage[mtpcal]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[cal=mt]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{Q}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try the code, it creates error

! Font U/mt2ms/m/it/10=mt2mst at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

What does it mean?

Comment: @TuanA.Nguyen - It means that the `mtpro2` package is not installed on your system. As I wrote in my answer, this isn't exactly surprising, as the package isn't free of charge and must be obtained from an external site. If you want to obtain this font package, do check out the information at https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html.

Comment: Thank you so much for your instruction. I'll try my best.

Comment: To the self-appointed vigilante who has down-voted -- anonymously, naturally -- not just one but two of my answers (including this one) so far today: Bravo!! I can only imagine the courage and resolve it must have taken to cast these surreptitious downvotes. The rush of satisfaction you must be receiving from casting these downvotes must more than make up for all the hard work and elaborate planning that evidently underlie your actions. By all means, keep up the great work!! But don't fool yourself into thinking that your downvotes will change *anything* about the way I do things on this site.

Comment: I almost understand nothing about what your said. I come from Vietnam, and in Vietnamese culture, you should say "thank you" for people who help you, especially, for certain detailed helps which improve your work. I'm so sorry if I make you feel that you was flattered by my "thank you". I will pay attention more on this problem.

Comment: @TuanA.Nguyen - My earlier comment (outburst?!) was not directed at you, but at whoever chose to downvote my answer.